# Class of new dependency not found in runtime after Android Maven build

Tags: android, android-build, android-maven-plugin

I have a pom.xml for my android application.
Now i want to add a new depedency through maven.

I have added a dependency like this

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.commonlib</groupId>
    <artifactId>commonlib</artifactId>
    <version>8.4.22</version>
</dependency>
```

Now the code is very well compiled and built an apk.
I run maven clean install command.
But when i run the application NoClassDefFoundError comes for the class.

My question do i have to do anything else apart from adding the depdency in pom. xml

cheers,
Sayrav

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you do not use Pro guard, if you want to use it edit proguard.cfg file.
To disable Pro guard go to Project Structure (on mac cmd + ;) --> select your module --> select proguard Tab --> Click disable

Hope that help.

Comment: Hi @molu2008 thanks for the reply...we have disabled pro guard

Answer (score 0):

You sure you have correct library name? I cannot see it on sonatype public https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/com/

Comment: Hi Peter thanks for the reply...i use it from our private nexus repo and its available :)

Comment: Without being able to see your build it is hard to judge. I suggest you to have look on this article and see if it helps http://javarevisited.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/noclassdeffounderror-exception-in.html